# Redirecting back to a specific div section with validation errors

Tags: html, laravel, validation

I have a page which has two divs which holds the login form and registration form

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="auth-buttons" >
        <a class="btn" id="btn-login">Login</a>
        <a class="btn" id="btn-register">Register</a>
    </div>
    <div id="lgn" class="btns">
        <form>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="reg" class="btns">
        <form>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

i have jquery which switches between the login and register

```js
<script>
    $('#reg').hide();
    $('#btn-login').click(function() {
        $('#reg').hide();
        $('#lgn').show();
    });
    $('#btn-register').click(function() {
        $('#lgn').hide();
        $('#reg').show();
    });
</script>
```

But when the register form has errors the form loads to the first page which is login how to i redirect to registration div with the errors?

here is what i tried but it didnt work

```php
if ( $validator->fails() ) {
    return redirect(url()->previous() .'#reg')->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try check location's hash:

```js
if (location.hash === '#reg') {
  $('#lgn').hide();
  $('#reg').show();
}
```

Comment: where should i put this

Comment: anywhere in your script, but after `$('#reg').hide();`

Comment: what exactly not working? your form doesn't open? or error messages don't appear in form?

Comment: the error messages appear on the form but the page loads the login page first i want it to load the registration form with errors if the user is on the registration page

Comment: add `console.log(location.hash)` in your js code and check what you see in console